# Can usual Android parsers parse Xforms?

Tags: android, xforms

In my Android app, I am using a specific API which returns responses as XFORMS documents.

Since XFORM is a "normal" XML, can I use the standard Android parsers to parse its content?

Under the term usual, I am referring to `XmlPullParser`.

Comment: have a look on this link may help you :http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xformstipjava/

Comment: @Android28 Have you used this method? I think I saw this before but I am not sure right now.

Comment: i came accros with this method in forums, which helped a user so i gave suggestion. give a try if it works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the purposes of standardizing XML is to ensure that any XML document can be parsed by any conforming parser, assuming that the parser understands the encoding used for the document.  If the responses you are getting are really XForms documents, then they are necessarily well formed XML; if XmlPullParser is a conforming XML parser, then it will certainly be able to parse the XForms documents.  If the parse does not succeed, you have evidence that either the document or the parser is non-conforming.

Comment: Being able to parse the document doesn't necessarily mean that the program can *do* anything with it though.

Comment: Quite true.  If the OP had asked about that, I would have assumed he cared about that.  Since the original question was about parsing, that was the question I answered.

Comment: Oh not a critique of your answer, but I'm sure its the next things people were going to ask. Congrats you parsed an XML file, now what?